# Copy selected text

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to copy the selected text from a WebBrowser Control. The usual way to do this is

```
ExecCommand("Copy", false)
```

However, this code does not work if the internet security settings are set to the highest. Is there another way to copy the selected text?

Comment: See the Remarks section of the [ExecWB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752087(v=vs.85)) method.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it does not really solve the issue. The users having this issue is unable and/or unwilling to change his security settings. Is there a way to force a different security zone inside our application?